# CKEditor 5 table toolbar config can't show Cell Properties in angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

In CKEditor 5 official demo, I can see the table content Toolbar has Cell properties, I really need that feature, but in my case, I config my table, there's never show up.

this is official demo

[image]

You can see the content Toolbar has Cell properties, in my case, the code are here:

TS:

```
Editor = ClassicEditor;
ckeditorConfig = {
 toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'insertTable' ],
 table: {
  contentToolbar: [ 'tableRow', 'tableColumn', 'mergeTableCells', 'tableCellProperties']
 }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ckeditor
 [config]="ckeditorConfig"
 [editor]="Editor"
 data="test">
</ckeditor>
```

But it's not work, there are:

[image]

In fact, in the official documentation, about table -> contentToolbar, there are not "Cell properties", they only 3 keyword, it's ['tableRow', 'tableColumn', 'mergeTableCells'], but I can't understand, isn't Cell properties in the contentToolbar?

Please help me, what should I do? big thank's!

Comment: Have you used the classic build? I think you might have to create a custom build with @ckeditor/ckeditor5-table for that.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work you must import them at the start of ckeditor.js like so:

```
import TableProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tableproperties';
import TableCellProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecellproperties';
```

then add to your plugins config like so

```
plugins: [ Table, TableToolbar, TableProperties, TableCellProperties, ... ]
```

Hope that fixes your issue!

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. In the GitHub link (https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/issues/187) it says that pre-built ckeditor5 bundles do not contain TableProperties and TableCellProperties plugins. If yu want to include the two plugins in your ClassicEditor or Decoupled Document Editor, then you need to create a custom build yourself. I need them as well but do not feel a bit of luck in this case.